# Why is the template argument deduction not working here?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I created two simple functions which get template parameters and an empty struct defining a type:

```
//S<T>::type results in T&
template <class T>
struct S
{
    typedef typename T& type;
};

//Example 1: get one parameter by reference and return it by value
template <class A>
A
temp(typename S<A>::type a1)
{
    return a1;
}

//Example 2: get two parameters by reference, perform the sum and return it
template <class A, class B>
B
temp2(typename S<A>::type a1, B a2)//typename struct S<B>::type a2)
{
    return a1 + a2;
}
```

The argument type is applied to the struct S to get the reference. I call them with some integer values but the compiler is unable to deduce the arguments:

```
int main()
{
    char c=6;
    int d=7;
    int res = temp(c);
    int res2 = temp2(d,7);
}
```

> Error 1   error C2783: 'A
> temp(S::type)' : could not deduce
> template argument for 'A'
>
> Error 2   error C2783: 'B
> temp2(S::type,B)' : could not
> deduce template argument for 'A'

---

Why is this happening? Is it that hard to see that the template arguments are *char* and *int* values?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just as first note, typename name is used when you mention a *dependent* name. So you don't need it here.

```
template <class T>
struct S
{
    typedef T& type;
};
```

Regarding the template instantiation, the problem is that `typename S<A>::type` characterizes a *nondeduced* context for A. When a template parameter is used only in a nondeduced context (the case for A in your functions) it's not taken into consideration for template argument deduction. The details are at section 14.8.2.4 of the C++ Standard (2003).

To make your call work, you need to explicitly specify the type:

```
temp<char>(c);
```

Answer (score 8):

It is looks like nondeduced context. According to C++ Standard 14.8.2.4/4:

> The nondeduced contexts are:
>
> - The *nested-name-specifier* of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*.
> - A type that is a *template-id* in which one or more of the *template-arguments* is an expression that references a *template-parameter*.
>
> When a type name is specified in a way that includes a nondeduced context, all of the types that comprise that type name are also nondeduced.  However, a compound type can include both deduced and nondeduced types.  [*Example*: If a type is specified as `A<T>::B<T2>`, both `T` and `T2` are nondeduced.  Likewise, if a type is specified as `A<I+J>::X<T>`, `I`, `J`, and `T` are nondeduced.  If a type is specified as `void f(typename  A<T>::B,  A<T>)`, the `T` in `A<T>::B` is nondeduced but the `T` in `A<T>` is deduced. ]

Comment: Can you please explain me this in simple words with examples : `The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.` I know nested name specifier is `X<T>::` and qualified id is one which has `::` as prefix , but unable conclude or understand whole thing. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: is it like ` (**The nested-name-specifier of a type**) that was specified using a qualified-id. ` or ` The nested-name-specifier of a (**type that was specified using a qualified-id.**) `

Answer (score 5):

Deduction works in the forward direction:

```
template <class T> void f(T);

f(2); // can deduce int from T
```

> Why is this happening?

It doesn't work in the backwards direction (your example):

```
template <class A> void g(typename S<A>::type);
```

> Is it that hard to see that the template arguments are char and int values?

Template deduction can do some magical (Turing-complete) things, but I don't think this is one of them.

You might use something like (untested):

```
template <class SA> void h(SA a1)
{
    STATIC_ASSERT(same_type<SA, S<A>::type>::value);
    typedef typename SA::type A;

    ...
}
```

Using your favorite static assert library (Boost has two).