# Prohibition of operator << calling

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have some code.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Test
{
   Test(bool v):flg(v) { }
   void func() { }
   typedef void (Test::*unspecified)();
   operator unspecified() const
   {
      return flg ? &Test::func : 0;
   }
   bool flg;
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, typename Test<T>::unspecified);

int main()
{
   Test<int> t(true);
   std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

Output is

```
1
```

It works fine, but i want to get undefined reference. If `Test` is `not template class` i get undefined reference. So, why compiler not use `operator <<` for function type and do standart conversion from `pointer to class-member` to `bool`?

Comment: See [Why is the template argument deduction not working here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268504/why-is-the-template-argument-deduction-not-working-here?lq=1)

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use `template<typename T> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Test<T>&);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `typename Test<T>::unspecified`, `T` is in a **non-deducible context**, since it appears to the left of a `::`. Thus your function template is never even considered, and the conversion to `unspecified` is used as the sole viable overload.

The short answer is simply that "templates don't work like that". Let me know if you want a longer answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry... No i don't need long answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say: "the actual parameter type is to the **right** of a `::`, which prevents the template argument `T` to the left of the `::` from being deduced."? I.e. the obstruction is that nested types do not participate in argument deduction.