# Why do I need to specify the template argument type of a templated function here?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void f1( T t )
{
    std::cout << "f1( " << t << " ) called." << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void f2( T t )
{
    std::cout << "f2( " << t << " ) called." << endl;
}

template <typename F, typename T>
void call( F && f, T t )
{
    f( t );
}

template <typename T>
void foo( T t )
{
    call( f1<T>, t ); // Why is <T> necessary?
                      // f1(t) is a valid expression!
    call( f2<T>, t );
}

void bar()
{
    foo( 1 );
}
```

In the function `foo()` I need to specify the template argument, even though `f1(t)` is a valid expression. That's kinda destroying some possibilities in my code. My questions:

1. Why do I need to specify the template argument?
2. How can I work around that limitation? (C++11 or C++14 allowed).

(BTW: I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010 and I get the error C2896, if I leave the `<T>` out.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`f1` is not a function, it's a template. You cannot pass a template as a function argument.

`f1<T>` is a function, so it can be passed.

Answer (score 7):

**1. Why do I need to specify the template argument?**

Well, `f1` is not an object, but a function template. You can only pass objects to functions.

**2. How can I work around that limitation? (C++11 or C++14 allowed).**

Use an object with a templated `operator()`. Just replace the definition of `f1()` with

```
struct { template <typename T> void operator()( T t )
{
    std::cout << "f1( " << t << " ) called." << endl;
} } f1;
```

and likewise for `f2()`. In C++14 you can write it even nicer

```
static const auto f1 = []( auto t )
{
    std::cout << "f1( " << t << " ) called." << endl;
};
```

Comment: Thanks to all the other answerers for their inspiring inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to wrap the templated functions f1 and f2 in non-templated classes and pass instances (or even types) around, e.g.

```
struct F1
{
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T t) const
  {
    std::cout << "F1::operator()(" << t << ") called" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct F2
{
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T t) const
  {
    std::cout << "F2::operator()(" << t << ") called" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename F, typename T>
void call(F && f, T t)
{
  f(t);
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
  static const F1 f1;
  static const F2 f2;
  call(f1, t);
  call(f2, t);
}

void bar()
{
  foo(1);
}
```

which produces the output:

F1::operator()(1) called

F2::operator()(1) called

Comment: +1 This is a nice variation of the same idea that I used in my answer. However, it might be useful (it depends on the OP's requirements) to make `call`, instead of receiving a `F`, create a local default-constructed instantiation of it. Then, in `foo` we could use `call<F1>(t);`.

Answer (score 1):

`f1(t)` is not a valid expression, since there is no function `f1`. There is only a *template* named `f1` from which a function `f1<T>` can be generated on compile time.

This *limitation* you talk about is a direct consequence of the compile-time type-checking. If you know the type of the argument of foo at compile time, there is no limitation, since you cann add it easily. If you don't know the type of the argument, you might have to use a derived class model instead of a template-driven idea.

Comment: Sure `f1(t)` is a valid expression inside `foo()`. It compiles fine.

Comment: Template parameter deduction does not work in specific patterns, perhaps this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268504/why-is-the-template-argument-deduction-not-working-here

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: It doesn't matter what *could* be a valid expression as it is used inside of `foo`. Templates are *not macros*; they don't just take anything and paste tokens together afterwards. Your template function takes an `F &&f`. That is a function parameter; it must be a *value*, which has a *type*. Templates neither are values nor have types. Therefore they can't be passed as function parameters.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: Yes, `f1(t)` is a valid expression due to function template argument deduction. The compiler can infer, based on the type of the parameter `t`, which instantiation of the function template `f1` to call - it replaces the `f1(t)` with `f1<T>(t)`. This is basically just some syntactic sugar. When you want to pass an instantiation of the `f1` template around, the compiler cannot help you, and you have to specify which one you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to mimic passing function templates (or overload sets) around as first-class values: "reify" them by turning them into function objects. Your code could be rewritten like this:

```
struct F1
{
  template <typename T>
  void operator ()( T t )
  {
    std::cout << "f1( " << t << " ) called." << endl;
  }
} f1;

struct F2
{
  template <typename T>
  void operator ()( T t )
  {
    std::cout << "f2( " << t << " ) called." << endl;
  }
} f2;

// Note that this function didn't change at all!
template <typename F, typename T>
void call( F && f, T t )
{
    f( t );
}
// Neither did this, expect that now you don't need the <T>
template <typename T>
void foo( T t )
{
    call( f1, t );
    call( f2, t );
}

void bar()
{
    foo( 1 );
    foo( 3.14 );
    foo( "Hello World" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation why it doesn't work has been given by [Angew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782465/angew) and [Urzeit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385414/urzeit).

What I'm trying to offer is a possible workaround for your problem. However, I cannot tell exactly whether this is appropriate or not for your case since the OP offers limited information on your specific designing requirements.

The first step is transforming `f1` and `f2` into template functor classes:

```
template <typename T>
class f1 {
public:
  void operator ()( T t ) {
      std::cout << "f1( " << t << " ) called." << std::endl;
  }
};
```

(Similarly for `f2`.) In this way, you can pass `f1` (and not `f1<T>`) as a template template parameter to `call` which is now defined in this way:

```
template <template <typename> class F, typename T>
void call( T t )
{
    F<T> f;
    f( t );
}
```

Notice that `F` is a template template parameter that binds to a template class taking one template type parameter (e.g. `f1`).

Finally, `foo` becomes this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo( T t )
{
    call<f1>( t );
    call<f2>( t );
}
```

`bar` is left as before.