# function template and iterators

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, type-deduction

I have this simple function template that's supposed to take a container as its template argument and print the contents:

```
template <typename T>
void print(typename T::iterator &it1,typename T::iterator &it2)
{
  while (it1 != it2) {
    std::cout<<*it1<<" ";
    ++it1;
  }
}
```

I'm passing an iterator range (tipically the first and the off-the-end iterators) and I added the typename keyword to the function parameters because the compiler needs to know that I'm talking about a type and not a static member.

but when I pass a vector to the function the compiler says it can't find any match for the call (the closest match being the function itself)
How can it be?

```
vector<double> dvec;
vector<double>::iterator it_b=dvec.begin();
vector<double>::iterator it_e=dvec.end();
print_it2(it_b,it_e);
```

the compiler says :

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed
                    could not deduce template parameter T
```

Comment: see [Why is the template argument deduction not working here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1268504/3953764)

Comment: It would work with `template <typename iterator> void print(iterator &it1, iterator &it2)`. The problem (for the compiler) is that you feed it an iterator and from that it cannot figure out that `T` must be `vector<double>`.

Comment: @BoPersson yes, I tryed that and it works indeed, it just deduce the type to be vector<double>::iterator doesn't it?

Comment: Theoretically `T` could also be some type `MySpecialContainer` that uses the same iterator class that vector does. The compiler cannot know that without instantiating ALL templates and check if any of them has a matching `iterator` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typename T::iterator` is a non-deduced context. The compiler has no way of knowing which `T` should be deduced because it doesn't understand the semantic connection between the type member `iterator` and a given `T`. It would need to search through all types to find a match and be able to somehow disambiguate collisions. This is unreasonable, so the standard doesn't allow it.

You could supply the type explicitly:

```
print<vector<double>>(it_b, it_e);
print<decltype(dvec)>(it_b, it_e); //c++11
```

But it would probably be easier to forget about the container from which the iterator came and let the compiler deduce the iterator type:

```
template <typename It>
void print (It& it1, It& it2);
```

Maybe you have a reason to pass the iterators by reference, but it seems like you should pass by value instead:

```
template <typename It>
void print (It it1, It it2);
```