# Create a template function for map<T1,T2> iterators

Tags: c++, templates, generics, template-function

So I am trying to make 4 template functions that do the following: sum a generic container, sum a map, sum generic container iterators, and sum generic map iterators. I have managed to do the first three, but I can't figure out the sum map iterators. Here is my code:

Sum.hpp

```
#ifndef SUM_HPP
#define SUM_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Sum Generic Container
template <typename T>
double Sum(const T& cont) {
    double sum = 0; 

    typename T::const_iterator iter = cont.begin();
    for (iter; iter != cont.end(); iter++) {
        sum += *iter;
    }

return sum;
}

//Sum Generic Map
template <typename T1, typename T2>
double Sum(const map<T1, T2>& mp) {
    double sum = 0;

    typename map<T1,T2>::const_iterator iter = mp.begin();
    for (iter; iter != mp.end(); iter++) {
        sum += iter->second;
    }

    return sum;
}

//Sum Generic Container Iterators
template <typename T>
double Sum(T& begin, const T& end) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (begin; begin != end; begin++) {
        sum += *begin;
    }

    return sum;
}

//Sum Generic Map Iterators
template <typename T1, typename T2>
double Sum(map<T1, T2>::iterator& begin, map<T1, T2>::iterator& end) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (begin; begin != end; begin++) {
        sum += begin->second;
    }

    return sum;
}


#endif
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "Sum.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //Map
    cout << "map" << endl;
    map<string, double> mp;

    mp["weight"] = 5.5;
    mp["height"] = 6.7;
    mp["length"] = 8.4;

    map<string, double>::iterator mp_iter_begin = mp.begin();
    map<string, double>::iterator mp_iter_end = mp.end();
    cout << Sum(mp_iter_begin, mp_iter_end) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the Sum() function it tries to call the Sum Generic Container Iterators function, if I comment out the Sum Generic Container Iterators function, I get a "no instance of overloaded function" error. Can anyone spot what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the template argument deduction not working here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268504/why-is-the-template-argument-deduction-not-working-here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to do it the way I wanted to with specialization:

```
//Sum Generic Container Iterators
template <typename T>
double Sum(T& begin, const T& end) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (begin; begin != end; begin++) {
        sum += *begin;
    }

    return sum;
}

//Sum Map<string, double> Iterators
template <>
double Sum(map<string, double>::iterator& begin, const map<string, double>::iterator& end) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (begin; begin != end; begin++) {
        sum += begin->second;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Note the importance of making sure the generic container iterator and map iterator function having matching arguments (both arguments are references and the second argument is a const for both template functions) or the specialization for `map<string,double>` will not work.

Comment: Note that as partial specialization is not allowed for function, you cannot handle `map<T, double>::iterator`. You have to list each combination that you want to support (and allocator...).

Comment: In addition, there are the `const_iterator` version too.

Comment: And a more complicated part: `map<K,V, A>::iterator` is not fully specified, so it might be possible that `map<K,V, A1>::iterator` and `map<K,V, A2>::iterator` are same type.

Comment: None of the standard library algorithms modify the iterators passed to them, so your functions will surprise users. For example, `Sum(m.begin(), m.end())` won't compile at all. And if I happened to pass named iterators like `Sum(i, j)`, the fact that `i` has changed could be even more surprising.

Comment: @aschepler This is just an academic exercise and not production code. Additionally, I had trouble finding a C++ example anywhere online that clearly demonstrated how to use specialization for my use case. If you have a way that can perform the sum on the map<string, double> that is generalizable and doesn't require lambda expressions or use the word auto, I would be interested.

Comment: Well, specializing function templates is almost never actually useful. Just plain overloading is more straightforward and more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

This belongs to [non-deduced contexts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts):

> 1) The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id:

That means for `map<T1, T2>::iterator`, the template parameter `T1` and `T2` can't be deduced.

You can solve the issue via [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), e.g.

```
//Sum Generic Container Iterators
template <typename T>
auto Sum(T begin, T end) -> remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin += *begin)> {

    remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin)> sum = 0;

    for (; begin != end; begin++) {
        sum += *begin;
    }

    return sum;
}

//Sum Generic Map Iterators
template <typename T>
auto Sum(T begin, T end) -> remove_reference_t<decltype(begin->second += begin->second)> {

    remove_reference_t<decltype(begin->second)> sum = 0;

    for (; begin != end; begin++) {
        sum += begin->second;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/EULA69367)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am aware that this is a solution, but I guess I should have specified I need to do this via specialization. I posted an answer below that does the trick.

Comment: @EliSquared But your solution only works with `map<string, double>`, but not `map<char, double>`, `map<int, double>` etc; you have to write the specializations for every possible types.

Comment: Yes that is true, but this is a homework assignment so I have to stay within the confines of what is asked. Your solution is better for the real world.